# Use DirectoryEntry to interact with IIS

Tags: c#, iis, com, interop

I am trying to connect to **IIS** using `DirectoryEntry` using below code

```
string hostName = "server1"
DirectoryEntry iis = new DirectoryEntry("IIS://" + hostname + "/w3svc");

foreach (DirectoryEntry node in iis.Children) // Getting exception on this line
{
  // some stuff
}
```

Exception Details

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80070057): The parameter is incorrect.
```

I think there is some issue with `server1` most probably something with iis on server1, because the same code is working fine for other servers. Just can't figure out what is the issue with `server1`.

Comment: Stop. It is time to use Microsoft.Web.Administration.

Comment: But I need to do it on a remote machine. Don't think Web.Administration can do that.

Comment: who told you it cannot? Try.